# How to enumerate ALL nodes in a Sprite Kit scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to enumerate all the nodes in my scene. Not just the ones that are a child of the scene itself, but also the children of those, and the children of those etc... So I want to be able to go through the whole node hierarchy.

Is there a method to do that without knowing how deep the node tree goes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, use [`enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:) and pass `//*` as the node name. You should be able to call that on any node.

It's actually one of the examples in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74):

> //* This search string matches every node in the node tree.

Comment: Thanks. I only tried using `*` but that only enumerates the direct children of the scene.

Comment: @Mike Is this possible with scenekit? How to get all the nodes in scenekit?