# Iterate All Sprite Nodes in SpriteKit using Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What is the best approach to iterate all SKSpriteNodes in a Scene using Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enumerate ALL nodes in a Sprite Kit scene?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749576/how-to-enumerate-all-nodes-in-a-sprite-kit-scene)

Answer (score 2):

If your sprites have their name properties set, you can use enumeration closure:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName(spriteName) {
            node, stop in
            // Do something with node.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Sample Swift code below.

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("SomeSprite*", usingBlock: {
        (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        // do something with node or stop
            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:0.8)
            node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
        }
    })
```